# Understanding the last statement in the following paragraph. on pg.145 in Royden (4th edition)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, normed-spaces

The paragraph is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand the last statement, is it because by the definition of the $p-$norm if $\{f_{n}\} \rightarrow f$ then we have $$(\int_{E} |f_{n} - f|^p)^{1/p} \rightarrow 0 $$ then upon taking the $p^th$ power on both sides we get  $$(\int_{E} |f_{n} - f|^p) \rightarrow 0. $$

Is my justification correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $u_{n}^{p}\rightarrow u^{p}$ is equivalent to $u_{n}\rightarrow u$, here $u_{n},u\geq 0$. Such an equivalence follows by the continuities of the maps $a\rightarrow a^{p}$ and $b\rightarrow b^{1/p}$ for $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: so my justification is correct.

Comment: Yes, your justification is correct.